# Reading Canon CR2 raw image files in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, parsing, image-file

Are there any free-to-use libraries for .NET so that I can read Canon's raw format, CR2, into my image processing application, retaining the full color depth? I believe it is a linear 14-bit/channel integer format, however some processing is required due to the layout of the image sensor array.

I don't want it in crappy 8-bit/channel precision, I want the highest possible color depth for my internal 32-bit/channel floating point format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the Canon SDK?  It's free to download, apparently, but you have to fill out a [request form](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/eos_1d?fileURL=ps_sdk_form&pageKeyCode=downloadLicense&id=0901e02480057a74_1&productOverviewCid=0901e0248003d099&keycode=Sdk_Lic) and agree to the license before getting a copy. (Disclaimer: I haven't used it.)

There's a site with a set of [forums for SDK users](http://canonsdk.com/phpBB3/) that might have some useful information.  Good luck!

Comment: +1. Be warned however: Canon's API is crap and their support is far far worse... *I* use it... :-(

Comment: When I first read the post that Canon offers an SDK I thought I was wrong they were just another corporate, but the last comment kinda ruined my hope a little. I'll take a look into it. They don't seem very open to Europe though, a search for 'Canon SDK' on the European site yields nada. Pah...

Comment: Why, oh, why, do the best devices always seem to come with the crappiest software/API/SDK/support? It's almost as if it's a law of nature.

Comment: "We don't believe in our customers, we believe in our business!" (don't remember the source of that quote though) :D

Comment: The links above appear to be outdated. I wasn't easily able to find replacement ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used [Freeimage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeimage/?source=dlp) for this.